# What can be done to increase my Ubuntu's speed?

Tags: 12.04

I have a 1GiB RAM and my operations are mostly using 3 internet tabs at a time, while working on a document (sometimes, like 53% of the time)
However, my WinXP seems to work faster than Ubuntu.
Is this a natural drawback of Ubuntu, or is there something I should do?
(I also constantly remove unwanted programs from time to time)

NOTE: I'm not *that* rich to buy 4 GB memory RAMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some other distribution or other desktop interface.

Unity is resource hungry.

Try using [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [mint with mate desktop](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to alternate window managers , slow responsiveness can come from buggy drivers. I have seen poor performance as a result of poor video drivers as well as some wireless cards.

Please identify your hardware, try booting with wireless disabled (use a cable) and see what happens.